# checkbox checking using triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have two checkboxes chkone,chktwo. when i am trying to check the first checkbox(chkone) i am disabling the second checkbox and ischeckd is true, but when i was executed disabling working properly but ischecked in not working?

```
       <CheckBox x:Name="chkone"
                                      Content="QA Review Mandatory" Margin="22,12,289,275"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Ischkone}"/>
            <CheckBox  x:Name="chktwo"
                                   Content="Question Mandatory" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Margin="22,85,0,201" IsChecked="{Binding Ischktwo}">
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkone,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkone,Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
```

Comment: looks like u r setting wrong ElementName.. It should be chkone.. right?

Comment: sorry, i edited the above question can u please look in to this....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code and let me know if you are still facing issue,

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkone"
          Content="QA Review Mandatory" Margin="22,12,289,275"
          IsChecked="{Binding Ischkone}"/>

<CheckBox  x:Name="chktwo"
           Content="Question Mandatory" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="22,85,0,201" >                
   <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkone,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkone,Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
```

Comment: i am ok with that answer but my binding value of second check box value is removed why ?

Comment: is it not possible without removing that binding , because i am doing some operations on viewmodels by using that binding name